# Removing orphaned entries in DB from deleting modules

Tags: 8, database

I made a custom module for drupal 8 and ended up just deleting the folder completely. Now when I try to enable other modules I'm getting a warning message that I'm missing that module.

How can I remove these orphaned entries in the database? Which table contains the module data that drupal checks upon initializing?